# Local Storage not working with window.location.replace?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, local-storage

I tried using Local Storage to store a variable to determine if a button can be used or not. This however is not working at all like I expected. Why is the Item getting shown as "null" and why is the console.log not working?

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index.html</title>
    <script>
        localStorage.setItem('status', 'unused')
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('status'))
        let usedButton = () => {
            localStorage.setItem('status', 'used')
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('status'))
            window.location.replace('index2.html')
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="usedButton()">Use me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

index2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index2.html</title>
    <script>
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('status'))
        let isButtonUsed = () => {
            if(localStorage.getItem('status') == 'used'){
                console.log('I was already used')
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="isButtonUsed()">Am I used?</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried making it so that the Button on index.html changes the localStorage variable status from 'unused' to 'used'. But on the 2nd page it is showing up as null and so the function is not working. I don't know how I can get a Button to work on one page and by clicking it disabling other buttons on other pages you redirect to.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How do you serve the files?

Comment: I just want to do it offline in one folder for a school project.

Comment: Files don't share local storage. You have to use a server.  With npx installed you can do `npx serve folder` to serve the files. You can also use live server in vscode